# btrfs-progs but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, btrfs

I am using [this guide](https://www.linux.com/BLOG/LINUX-101-CHECK-DISK-SPACE-COMMAND) to check available disk space. For that, I tried using the last option to see space in one full number. But I am unable to see it.

This is the error I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
btrfs-tools : Depends: btrfs-progs but it is not going to be installed  
libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.8-0.2)
but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed  libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks:
libfreetype6 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed 
libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am not sure what this error means.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Please see log

```
root@asdsd:/home# sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done   
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.   
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
 btrfs-tools : Depends: btrfs-progs but it is not going to be installed   
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.8-0.2) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed   
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed   
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed   
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).   
root@asdsd:/home# sudo apt --fix-broken install   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done   
Correcting dependencies... Done   
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:   
  bamfdaemon blt command-not-found-data gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0   
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gtk3-nocsd hud intel-gpu-tools libatkmm-1.6-1v5   
  libaudio2:i386 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcolumbus1-common libcolumbus1v5 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libframe6   
  libgeis1 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libglewmx1.13 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrail6 libgsettings-qt1 libgtk3-nocsd0 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5   
  libice6:i386 liblirc-client0 libmetacity1 libmng2:i386 libmodplug1 libmpdec2:i386 libnih-dbus1 libnm-gtk0 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common   
  libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libpng12-0:i386 libpython-all-dev libpython3-stdlib:i386 libpython3.6-minimal:i386 libpython3.6-stdlib:i386   
  libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386   
  libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386   
  libqtwebkit4:i386 libreadline7:i386 libsgutils2-2 libsignon-glib1 libsm6:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libtbb2 libtimezonemap-data   
  libtimezonemap1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-misc4 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzip5 metacity-common   
  mongo-tools nux-tools php-http-request php-net-socket php-net-url php-net-url2 python-all python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend   
  python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus python-enum34 python-idna python-ipaddress python-keyring python-keyrings.alt   
  python-secretstorage python-wheel python-xdg python3-blinker python3-bs4 python3-feedparser python3-html5lib python3-jwt   
  python3-webencodings qt-at-spi:i386 session-shortcuts sni-qt:i386 tk8.6-blt2.5 unity-asset-pool unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files   
  unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-schemas unity-scope-home unity-scope-video-remote unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner   
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.   
The following additional packages will be installed:   
  libfreetype6   
The following packages will be upgraded:   
  libfreetype6   
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 268 not upgraded.   
2 not fully installed or removed.   
Need to get 0 B/335 kB of archives.   
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.   
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y   
(Reading database ... 246177 files and directories currently installed.)   
Preparing to unpack .../libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...   
Unpacking libfreetype6:amd64 (2.8.1-2ubuntu2) over (2.8-0.2) ...   
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):   
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libfreetype6:amd64   
Errors were encountered while processing:   
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb   
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)   
root@asdsd:/home# sudo apt autoclean;   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done   
Del php7.1-curl 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [28.8 kB]   
Del libglib2.0-dev 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [1,384 kB]   
Del php7.2-opcache 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [165 kB]   
Del cups-ppdc 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [26.8 kB]   
Del php7.2-tidy 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [16.9 kB]   
Del php7.3-readline 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.0 kB]   
Del php7.2-odbc 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [30.4 kB]   
Del mutter 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.2 [15.5 kB]   
Del libsystemd0 237-3ubuntu10.21 [221 kB]   
Del cups-server-common 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [415 kB]   
Del g++ 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2 [1,568 B]   
Del binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1 [1,854 kB]   
Del php7.1-intl 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [129 kB]   
Del gcc-7-base 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [19.0 kB]   
Del php7.2-snmp 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [18.5 kB]   
Del php7.1-cli 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,344 kB]   
Del php7.2-mbstring 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [485 kB]   
Del libbinutils 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1 [501 kB]   
Del libcups2 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [225 kB]   
Del php5.6-json 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [17.9 kB]   
Del cups 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [191 kB]   
Del php7.2-fpm 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,412 kB]   
Del php7.2-cgi 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,368 kB]   
Del php5.6-curl 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [28.3 kB]   
Del php7.2-bcmath 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.4 kB]   
Del libudev1 237-3ubuntu10.21 [57.3 kB]   
Del libapache2-mod-php7.2 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,350 kB]   
Del php7.1-json 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [17.5 kB]   
Del php7.3-zip 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [20.4 kB]   
Del libgfortran4 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [492 kB]   
Del php7.1-mbstring 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [469 kB]   
Del php7.3-mysql 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [116 kB]   
Del gcc-8-base 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [18.6 kB]   
Del php7.2-gmp 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [20.2 kB]   
Del php7.3-bz2 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [10.2 kB]   
Del php7.2-gd 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.2 kB]   
Del php7.1-mysql 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [120 kB]   
Del libudev1 237-3ubuntu10.21 [54.0 kB]   
Del libgomp1 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [76.4 kB]   
Del php7.2-json 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [18.8 kB]   
Del php7.2-phpdbg 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,448 kB]   
Del libmutter-2-0 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.2 [1,208 kB]   
Del mutter-common 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.2 [13.3 kB]   
Del php7.1-zip 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [20.2 kB]   
Del systemd-sysv 237-3ubuntu10.21 [11.6 kB]   
Del libglib2.0-0 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [1,237 kB]   
Del libcupsimage2 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [18.6 kB]   
Del php7.1-gmp 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [21.3 kB]   
Del php5.6-readline 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.9 kB]   
Del php7.3-xml 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [106 kB]   
Del libgcc1 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [40.7 kB]   
Del php7.2-soap 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [113 kB]   
Del cups-common 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [206 kB]   
Del php7.2-pgsql 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [56.0 kB]   
Del libapache2-mod-php7.1 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,284 kB]   
Del php7.2-mysql 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [117 kB]   
Del php7.2-dev 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [555 kB]   
Del libsystemd0 237-3ubuntu10.21 [204 kB]   
Del php7.1-xml 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [115 kB]   
Del php7.1-common 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [903 kB]   
Del libstdc++6 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [400 kB]   
Del php7.3-mbstring 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [511 kB]   
Del php5.6-common 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [2,764 kB]   
Del libglib2.0-dev-bin 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [102 kB]   
Del libasan4 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [359 kB]   
Del php7.2-pspell 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [8,504 B]   
Del libquadmath0 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [134 kB]   
Del libtsan0 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [288 kB]   
Del libglib2.0-data 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [4,720 B]   
Del liblsan0 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [133 kB]   
Del g++-7 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [7,575 kB]   
Del libpam-systemd 237-3ubuntu10.21 [108 kB]   
Del software-properties-gtk 0.96.24.32.8 [62.3 kB]   
Del php7.3-cli 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,376 kB]   
Del php7.2-ldap 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [23.7 kB]   
Del php7.3-curl 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [29.6 kB]   
Del libstdc++6 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [432 kB]   
Del gir1.2-mutter-2 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.2 [139 kB]   
Del php7.2-dba 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [23.2 kB]   
Del cpp-7 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [6,740 kB]   
Del gcc-7 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [7,462 kB]   
Del php7.3-common 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [939 kB]   
Del php7.2-recode 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [5,644 B]   
Del php7.2-curl 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [28.8 kB]   
Del php7.2-zip 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [20.6 kB]   
Del php7.1-readline 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.5 kB]   
Del gcc 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2 [5,184 B]   
Del php7.3-json 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [18.4 kB]   
Del software-properties-common 0.96.24.32.8 [9,992 B]   
Del cups-client 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [139 kB]   
Del php7.2-intl 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [125 kB]   
Del libnss-systemd 237-3ubuntu10.21 [105 kB]   
Del libcupsppdc1 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [45.0 kB]   
Del binutils-common 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1 [193 kB]   
Del systemd 237-3ubuntu10.21 [2,901 kB]   
Del php7.1-gd 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.9 kB]   
Del cups-core-drivers 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [27.8 kB]   
Del php7.3 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [35.8 kB]   
Del libnss-myhostname 237-3ubuntu10.21 [34.0 kB]   
Del php7.2-sybase 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [11.3 kB]   
Del php7.0-common 7.0.33-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [896 kB]   
Del libcupsmime1 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [13.2 kB]   
Del udev 237-3ubuntu10.21 [1,102 kB]   
Del php7.0-curl 7.0.33-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.9 kB]   
Del libglib2.0-bin 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [68.9 kB]   
Del libapache2-mod-php5.6 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,256 kB]   
Del php7.2 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [49.0 kB]   
Del libcups2 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [211 kB]   
Del libapache2-mod-php7.3 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,322 kB]   
Del php7.2-imap 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [29.1 kB]   
Del libglib2.0-0 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [1,169 kB]   
Del libitm1 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [27.9 kB]   
Del php7.2-sqlite3 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [25.4 kB]   
Del cups-ipp-utils 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [210 kB]   
Del libubsan0 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [126 kB]   
Del php7.2-bz2 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [10.3 kB]   
Del cups-bsd 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [38.4 kB]   
Del python3-software-properties 0.96.24.32.8 [23.7 kB]   
Del libcc1-0 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [47.4 kB]   
Del cups-daemon 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [296 kB]   
Del php7.2-common 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [926 kB]   
Del libatomic1 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [9,180 B]   
Del php7.2-xmlrpc 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.8 kB]   
Del libcilkrts5 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [42.5 kB]   
Del php7.2-cli 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,407 kB]   
Del php5.6 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [263 kB]   
Del php7.1-bcmath 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.9 kB]   
Del php7.0-gmp 7.0.33-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [21.6 kB]   
Del libstdc++-7-dev 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [1,467 kB]   
Del php7.3-opcache 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [181 kB]   
Del libgcc1 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [48.2 kB]   
Del php7.2-xml 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [107 kB]   
Del php7.3-odbc 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [30.5 kB]   
Del php5.6-cli 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,301 kB]   
Del cpp 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2 [27.6 kB]   
Del php7.3-intl 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [124 kB]   
Del libgcc-7-dev 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 [2,381 kB]   
Del php5.6-opcache 5.6.40-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [62.6 kB]   
Del gcc-8-base 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [18.7 kB]   
Del libmpx2 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04 [11.6 kB]   
Del php7.2-interbase 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [40.2 kB]   
Del libcupscgi1 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [27.4 kB]   
Del php7.3-gd 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [26.9 kB]   
Del php7.2-xsl 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [48.7 kB]   
Del binutils 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1 [3,396 B]   
Del php7.1 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [62.0 kB]   
Del php7.0-mcrypt 7.0.33-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [14.9 kB]   
Del php7.1-opcache 7.1.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [147 kB]   
Del php7.2-readline 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.2 kB]   
Del php7.2-enchant 7.2.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [9,108 B]   
Del php7.3-bcmath 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.0 kB]   
root@asdsd:/home# sudo apt autoremove;    
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done   
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.   
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.8-0.2) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is installed   
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is installed   
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is installed   
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).   
root@asdsd:/home# sudo apt update   
Ign:1 http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian bionic InRelease   
Get:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,182 B]                                                                       
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease                                                                        
Hit:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release                                                                          
Hit:5 http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian bionic Release                                                                                  
Get:6 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease [10.2 kB]                                                                                     
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                           
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                                                                                
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                        
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]   
Get:11 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease [9,388 B]                                                                                 
Get:12 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [125 kB]                                                             
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                           
Hit:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                       
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                             
Ign:20 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial InRelease                                                
Get:21 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial Release [66.8 kB]                                                              
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                       
Get:23 http://archive.canonical.com bionic/partner i386 Packages [2,316 B]                                                     
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                        
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                         
Get:26 http://archive.canonical.com bionic/partner amd64 Packages [2,316 B]                                   
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [338 kB]                 
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [447 kB]   
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [156 kB]                                                              
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.1 kB]                                                      
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [10.4 kB]                                                         
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [31.7 kB]                                                         
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [563 kB]                                                           
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [570 kB]                                                          
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [185 kB]                                                          
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.2 kB]                                                  
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]                                                     
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [111 kB]                                                      
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]                                                
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,224 B]                                                 
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]                                                 
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [949 kB]                                                            
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [965 kB]                                                           
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [287 kB]                                                           
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [249 kB]                                                    
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [203 kB]                                                       
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [423 kB]                                                       
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [676 kB]                                                               
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [555 kB]                                                                
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [249 kB]                                                               
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]                                                        
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.7 kB]                                                          
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [134 kB]                                                           
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                     
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' does not have a Release file.   
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.   
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.   
root@asdsd:/home# sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done   
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.   
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
 btrfs-tools : Depends: btrfs-progs but it is not going to be installed   
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.8-0.2) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed   
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed   
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed   
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).   
root@asdsd:/home#
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, try first to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and then the commands `sudo apt autoclean; sudo apt autoremove; sudo apt update` before retrying `sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools` command.

Comment: I did that as per error solving suggestions, but still no luck!

Comment: Please, post outputs of the commands in your original question text. And also correct the heading of this topic.

Comment: Output mentioned, command fired mentioned, what problem I am facing Mentioned, I don't understand what extra to update in question, can you please help me with this?

Comment: I am talking about the five commands I mentioned in my first comment. What output is produced by each command executed in the order mentioned in my comment?

Comment: I updated question. Please check

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I think the errors related to `libfreetype6` package and the repository `'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release'` should be handled first. (Try to remove/purge and then reinstall the package. Also remove the indicated repository to prevent further error messages.)